# $http method is being ignored

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I have this code:

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data
    })
```

But, it sends the request as a GET. Like I have no idea what is going, it works fine on my desktop but on my laptop, it seems to not work.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I also tried $http.post() with no success.

Thanks,

Comment: I take it your are looking in your browser debugging tools like Chromes network tab?

Comment: @mindparse Yeah, I am looking in Chrome debug tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no concern of laptop or desktop. For more clarification you can try

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```